# Puppeteer sign in to TikTok

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Edit: I found the issue. If anyone else is having this issue, here is the code that worked:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.tiktok.com/login/phone-oremail/email');
await page.type('input[name=email]', 'email', {delay: 20})
await page.type('input[name=password]', 'password', {delay: 20})

await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('button[type=submit]').click(); });
```

Comment: I was able to get the login to work, but have found issues with the captcha. It looks like platforms like 2captcha don't support TikTok's captcha either. How did you get around this if you don't mind sharing?

Comment: I dont recall getting around this so I just temporarily showed the browser window and got the user to solve the captcha. It's a bad solution but I'm not sure about other ways. I suggest looking at some open-source (unofficial) TikTok APIs because it might better suit your needs.